# Hibernate and serialization

Tags: java, hibernate, serialization

In our application  we have a dual persistence. First, the entity can be saved online in a MySQL DB (we are using Hibernate), second the entity can be saved locally through serialization.

The entity I'm speaking of is an object of the class `User` which contains a `KnowledgeBase` object and that `KnowledgeBase` contains two lists of entities (`List<Card>` and `List<Deck>`).

Both persistences work fine in separate, but there are problems when I try to de-serialize a serialized `User` object that I loaded from the database, i.e. that has been trough Hibernate at least once (well, twice, actually).

What I've noticed is the the `ArrayList` inside `KnowledgeBase` are replaced by `PersistentBag`. Could that that be the source of my problem?

Another guess might be that lazy loading causes these troubles... Is there a way to tell Hibernate to fully load an object at some point? (Apart from eager loading...)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, `Hibernate.initialize(..)` initializes objects and collections.

Then, if needed, you can replace the collections with the regular `java.util` ones using the copy-constructor: `setList(new ArrayList(list))`

Comment: It is indeed initializes objects and collections, but it keeps the Hibernate proprietary collection types. We had that problem with marshalling/unmarshalling Hibernate-loaded objects using XStream. Is there a better way than just reloading a Hibernate-loaded object into a normally instantiated object of the same type?

Comment: Thanks! I'll certainly use this next time I'll have to marshal Hibernate-loaded entities to XML using XStream.

Comment: @Olaf btw, I believe PersistentBag should also support nice serialization, if the session is there and the collection is initualized

Comment: Will Hibernate.initialize() initialize collections and entities recursively? For example if a collection contains entities with collections of their own? Will those get initialized?

Comment: Hmmm. Currently gettin `LazyInitializationException` because a collection inside the elements of a collection inside an entity.

Comment: you'd have to initialize everything recursively yourself

Comment: So, more exactly `KnowledgeBase`contains `List<Card>`where each `Card`contain `List<Category>`. How do I initialize the catogory-list?

Comment: iterate all cards, and call Hibernate.Initialize on the category list